# gate descriptor is not valid sys seg

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, osdev

i use Bochs to emulate my kernel. I wrote IDT struct, load_idt function and keyboard handler procedure. Print handler, called by keyboard handler, just read 0x60 port and put char on screen.
When Bochs work and i press any key it restarts. And in log file:

```
00080068800e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x21)
00080068800e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x0d)
00080068800e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)
```

my code:

```
struct IDT
{
    unsigned short offset_lowerbits;
    unsigned short offset_higherbits;
    unsigned short selector;
    unsigned char zero;
    unsigned char type_attributes;
};

struct IDT IDT_deskriptors[IDT_SIZE];

extern "C" void IDT_init()
{
    unsigned long idt_ptr[2];
    unsigned long idt_address = (unsigned long)IDT_deskriptors;
    idt_ptr[0] = (sizeof(struct IDT) * IDT_SIZE) + ((idt_address & 0xffff) << 16);
    idt_ptr[1] = idt_address >> 16;

    unsigned long kbd_address = (unsigned long)kbd_handler;
    IDT_deskriptors[0x21].offset_lowerbits = (kbd_address & 0xffff);
    IDT_deskriptors[0x21].offset_higherbits = (kbd_address & 0xffff0000) >> 16;
    IDT_deskriptors[0x21].zero = 0;
    IDT_deskriptors[0x21].selector = 0x08;
    IDT_deskriptors[0x21].type_attributes = 0x8e;
    
    outb(0x20, 0x11);
    outb(0xA0, 0x11);

    outb(0x21, 0x20);
    outb(0xA1, 0x28);

    outb(0x21, 0x04); 
    outb(0xA1, 0x02); 

    outb(0x21, 0x01);
    outb(0xA1, 0x01);


    outb(0x21, 0x0);
    outb(0xA1, 0x0);

    load_idt(idt_ptr);
}


extern "C" void kmain(void)
{
    IDT_init();
    kbd_init();
    while (1)
    {
        asm("hlt");
    };
}
```

Asm functions

```
load_idt:
    mov edx, [esp + 4]
    lidt [edx]
    sti 
    iretd

kbd_handler:  
    call print_handler
    iretd
```

I think, my problem in IDT filling and i used memset function to set 0 unused deskriptors. But Bochs gives:

```
00185622638e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): vector must be within IDT table limits, IDT.limit = 0x0
00185622638e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): vector must be within IDT table limits, IDT.limit = 0x0
00185622638e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): vector must be within IDT table limits, IDT.limit = 0x0
```

Comment: IDT.limit = 0x0 the size in your IDT pointer is 0 so it is faulting

Comment: By any chance are you compiling this as 64-bit code rather than 32-bit code? What options do you pass to your C compiler? You also mention memset but I don't see that in the code.

Comment: I just noticed in your assembly function `load_idt` ends with `iretd`. That isn't an interrupt handler and should be `ret`

Comment: to compile i use: 1)nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kernel.o
 2) g++ -fno-pic -m32 -o kernel.bin master.cpp kernel.o -nostdlib -ffreestanding -std=c++11 -mno-red-zone -fno-exceptions -nostdlib -fno-rtti -Wall -Wextra -T linker.ld

Comment: And to link with ld: ENTRY(_start)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x7c00;
    .text :
    {
        *(._start)
        *(.text)
 . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
 . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
 . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
}

Comment: So it is 32-bit code which eliminates one problem. The `iretd` in `idt_init` has to be fixed. There may be problems in the code you don't show. This isn't a minimal complete example so it is hard to troubleshoot. Do you have your code on github or similar service? Something else to note: Just before calling `load_idt` you do this `outb(0x21, 0x0); outb(0xA1, 0x0);` at the end. Setting those both to 0 enables all interrupts. When you do `sti` you may get interrupts you haven't handled - like the timer at interrupt 0x20. THat will potentially cause failures.

Comment: Thanks for the adviсe. my git https://github.com/DmitryVes/myKernel

Comment: Ah I missed the fact that your IDT entries structure is wrong. It needs to be `struct IDT
{
    unsigned short offset_lowerbits; unsigned short selector; unsigned char zero; unsigned char type_attributes; unsigned short offset_higherbits;
};` . The order of the members in yours is wrong and the cause of some of the issues.

Comment: I should point out that your implementation of `memset` is buggy and the call to `memset` you did uses the wrong parameters and would cause zeroes to be written well beyond the end of the `IDT_deskriptors` array

Comment: Thanks a lot, when i changed order, all worked, i didn't really take into account descriptor constitution